# How do I get specific values from checked rows in MVC razor view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Ok, so I have this partial view (part of an MVC application) which just displays data from a view in the database.

```
@model IEnumerable<TransportPlanner.Models.TRANSPORT_PLANNER_VIEW>
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>@Html.CheckBox("HeaderCheck")</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)</th>
        ....
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Volume)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Weight)</th>
        ....
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.CheckBox("RowCheck")</th>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)</td>
            ....
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Volume)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Weight)</td>
            ....
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I want to be able to find a way in which I can get the values for the `Volume` and `Weight` fields of only the checked rows (after checking them), and add them to get the total (which is displayed but not stored).

For example, once I get the results displayed on screen, and I check 3 rows (having the values of 'weight' as 5, 10 and 15), then value displayed should be '30' (sum of the weights). Similarly, if I remove the checkbox for the row having weight as '5', then the value displayed should be '25'.

My front end skills are almost non-existent, and I have scourged over the internet for nearly 12 hours but not found a way to do it. I know that I need to either use JavaScript (or some flavour of it like JQuery) or Ajax (if I need the values updates dynamically as I check/uncheck them).

What is the best way to achieve this, without updating my model? I don't have the luxury of time because I am the only developer at my workplace, and this is the first step of a huge task I need to complete in 3 weeks.

Comment: hi one question are these vales are  already calculated you just need to hide and show them based on click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@Html.CheckBox("RowCheck")` is generating invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes). Replace it with

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
```

Then add class names to the `<td>` elements for `Volume` and `Weight`

```
<td class="volume">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Volume)</td>
<td class="weight">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Weight)</td>
```

And assuming you want to display the totals in the table footer, add the following html to the `<table>` element (note you should also use the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` in your table

```
<table>
    ....
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            ....
            <td id="totalvolume"><td>
            <td id="totalweight"><td>
            ....
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Then you can use javascript/jquery to handle the change event of the checkboxes, and sum the values in each row. Using jquery:

```
$('.checkbox').change(function() {
    var totalVolume = 0;
    var totalWeight = 0;
    var selected = $('.checkbox:checked'); // get the selected checkboxes
    $.each(selected, function(index, item) { // loop through the selected checkboxes
        var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // get the containing tr element
        totalVolume += Number(row.find('.volume').text());
        totalWeight += Number(row.find('.weight').text());
    })
    // display the totals
    $('#totalvolume').text(totalVolume);
    $('#totalweight').text(totalWeight);
});
```

Note, the above code assumes the values of properties `Volume` and `Weight` are numeric (without any formatting)